Choosing Between IAM Users and AWS Organizations for Department Management
I have 5 departments with 10 employees each. Should I create 50 IAM users and 5 IAM user groups, associating employees with the correct group? Or should I create an AWS Organization with 5 Organizational Units (OUs) and 50 accounts, placing them in the appropriate OUs?

do whatever works the best for you ... asking for opinions is not allowed here ... please ask a question that has a very limited number of correct answers

what is the recommended approach though ?

Ideally you would not have IAM Users at all. See AWS Identity and Access Management Best Practices and Security best practices in IAM. Instead use identity federation and temporary credentials.

For a small team of 50 employees, sticking with IAM Users and Groups is usually simpler and gets the job done.
But if you’re planning to grow quickly or need stronger separation between departments, using an AWS Organization with OUs might be a better fit.
It really comes down to your company's needs and future plans.
